# Does Odo ever return to being a changeling after he had become human?

Tags: star-trek-ds9

At the end of season 4 of [Star Trek: Deep Space Nine](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0708509/?ref_=ttep_ep25), in the episode, "Broken Link," Odo is made human.  Does he ever return to being a changeling?  He is still human in the first episode of season 5. [DS9 Season 5](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106145/episodes?season=5)

Comment: Doesn't knowing this remove some of the tension and anticipation of watching the rest of the series?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Star Trek Deep Space Nine Season 5 Episode 12 has an infant changeling basically absorbing into him turning him back into a changeling.

Comment: Watched that episode tonight.  I had originally recorded all episodes on VHS and watched them, but forgot most of the shows.  They are all new to me again now.